# Apply mysql query to each table in a database

Tags: mysql

is there a way to apply a query to each table in a mysql database?

Something like

```
SELECT count(*) FROM {ALL TABLES}
-- gives the number of count(*) in each Table
```

and

```
DELETE FROM {ALL TABLES}
-- Like DELETE FROM TABLE applied on each Table
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
select sum(table_rows) as total_rows
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'your_db_name'
```

beware this is just an approximate value

In order to delete the contents of all your tables you can do something like this

```
select concat('truncate ',table_name,';')
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'your_db_name'
```

Then run the output of this query.

**UPDATE.**

This is a stored procedure to apply `truncate table` to all tables in a specific database

```
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists delete_contents //
create procedure delete_contents (in db_name varchar(100))
begin
declare finish int default 0;
declare tab varchar(100);
declare cur_tables cursor for select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema = db_name and table_type = 'base table';
declare continue handler for not found set finish = 1;
open cur_tables;
my_loop:loop
fetch cur_tables into tab;
if finish = 1 then
leave my_loop;
end if;

set @str = concat('truncate ', tab);
prepare stmt from @str;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
end loop;
close cur_tables;
end; //
delimiter ;

call delete_contents('your_db_name');
```

Comment: Your updated procedure is very useful. It looks like `db_name` doesn't affect anything though with the current setup (I removed it entirely without issue in the procedure).

Comment: Nice. To show individual count of entries in each table: <code>select table_name,table_rows from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'your_db_name'</code>

Answer (score 0):

**if tables are related by any field you can use alias of tables like**

```
select count(*) from table1 tb1, table2 tb2, table3 tb3 where
tb1.field1 = tb2.field2 and tb2.field2 = tb3.field3
```

similary,

```
delete from table1 tb1, table2 tb2, table3 tb3 where
tb1.field1 = tb2.field2 and tb2.field2 = tb3.field3
```

you can include conditions as per you requirements.

**If tables have no relation then use below**

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE someCondition) as count1, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE someCondition) as count2,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table3 WHERE someCondition) as count3
```

**you can remove where clause if there is no conditions.**

OUTPUT:

|count1 | count2 | count3|

|50     |36      |21     |