# How to find the last modified rows across certain tables

Tags: mysql

How to find the last modified rows across certain tables or all tables in my database.
All tables in our database have (created_at, updated_at datetime columns).

I want the result set to say something like ..

```
table foo, id=10000, .... (equivalent of select * on that row)

table boo, id=20000, ....

table bar, id=30000, ....
```

This will help me find the time at which the table was modified for a certain row.

Comment: Have you tried `ORDER BY updated_at DESC` and `LIMIT 1` to get the last updated record from the table? Isn't that what you need?

Comment: Use triggers to save logs on running update queries and use this log to get the updated row details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either

```
Select * from Tbl where updated_at=max(updated_at)
```

Or

```
Select * from Tbl order by updated_at DESC limit 1
```

If you want only the last row

To run it on all the tables, use:

```
select concat('Select * from ',table_name,' where updated_at=max(updated_at);')
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'your_db_name'
```

And then run the result as a query

This can be done automatically using the [execute command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398847/apply-mysql-query-to-each-table-in-a-database)