# Run an ALTER TABLE across all like tables (containing the same schema) in MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I have a database that contains a table per client, each table has the same columns in them.  We're talking a few thousand client tables.

I need to add new columns to each of these tables for new development but cannot find a way to recurse all the tables in the database to add the columns.  I know MS SQL has something sp_MSforeachtable which does maybe what I'm asking but I don't know if MySQL has anything similar?

Comment: Well for start you shouldnt have a different table for user. Instead you create a table `users` and assign an `user_id` that way when you add a column everyone get that column

Comment: Compose the `ALTER TABLE` statement dynamically. Then execute it. Check out this link: https://www.otreva.com/blog/mysql-execute-immediate-solution/

Comment: Juan, this is all individual client data stored per client per table, not designed by me, already established.

Robert, thank you for the link but I do not understand the concept, my knowledge of MySQL is limited.  I was wondering if there was a way to query the schema and then recurse through the resultset to add the required columns, I assume that is the dynamic statement you talk about?  Can it be scripted another way or could you clarify.

Thank you both

Comment: _client data stored per client per table.._ Does that mean if you have 1.000.000 users you will have 1.000.000 tables??

Comment: Yes B001, for each client there is a corresponding table added to the specific database and all the columns/data reside there.

Comment: _Yes...for each client..._ Sounds like it is time to make a db design optimization before adding more tables to that monster... this approach is misusing mysql definitley

Comment: @b001 While I agree with you and we have a redesign in progress, I still in the meantime need to add columns to each of the tables in the database to support new (parallel) development.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this previous answer in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398847/apply-mysql-query-to-each-table-in-a-database) you could do something like this :

```
select concat('ALTER TABLE `',table_name,'` ADD `test` INT NOT NULL AFTER `column_x`;')
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'your_db_name'
```

Then remove the few tables not about client (here's hoping client is the only entity to have "private table") or if possible add a condition on the `table_name` (like `AND table_name LIKE "client_%"`), and execute the whole batch.

The 2nd solution, to use procedure, is too complex (for me) for this use case, but maybe someone more skilled than me in PLSQL won't agree.